# PHP Set value based on dropdown selection

Tags: php

I have a dropdown that lists all addresses saved for a customer. Based on the customer selection of address, I have to set the delivery address in my session.

This is the outcome I would like after the selection was made:
`$_SESSION['order']['delivery']['address'] = $choice['id']`

The `$choice['id']` is the value that I retrieve from the array and corresponds the the ID of the delivery address.

I get my values for `$address` comes from:
`$address = $db->get_delivery_addresses_by_user_id($_SESSION['js_user_id']);`

My Dropdown code is:

```
<label class="required" for="delivery_address">Please select Address</label>
                <div class="select-holder">
                  <form  name="select-address-form" method="POST" action="">
                    <select name="delivery_address" id="delivery_address">
                      <option value="">Select Address</option>
                      <?php
                      foreach($address as $id => $choice) {
                        echo "<option value=" . $choice['id'] . ">" . $choice['address_name'] . "</option>";
                      } ?>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="set address">
                  </form>
                </div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you simply define as follows after the form is submitted: `$_SESSION['order']['delivery']['address'] = $_POST['delivery_address'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required somewhere above (you most likely have this):

```
session_start();
```

Then do something with the data on `POST`:

```
if (isset($_POST['delivery_address'])){
  $_SESSION['order']['delivery']['address'] = $_POST['delivery_address'];
  session_write_close();
  header("Location:" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //refresh page
  exit; //ensure no more code execution
}
```

> Note: you must place the code before any text is output to the browser,
>   **or the redirect will not work**. That means putting it before
>   `<!DOCTYPE>` is printed.

You can verify it works by printing out the session array somewhere:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Why would you need a location header here?

Comment: @MarkusAO he asked the best way to handle the situation -- the location header is to get the browser back out of `POST`.

Comment: Ah I see, cool. Didn't notice the OP needing to get out of `POST`.